# Why Tkinter and PIL image is not working on Windows Task Scheduler but works on cmd

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10

I have some trouble at showing Tkinter + PIL image on the Windows Task Scheduler. It is works flawlessly when i compile using CMD, but the image won't appear on Task Scheduler.

Here is some of my simple code:

```
 import Tkinter as tk
 import time
 from PIL import ImageTk, Image


 def close():
      global root
      root.quit()
      return; 

 root = tk.Tk()
 img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\RedAlert.jpg'))

 def alert():
     global img

     panel = tk.Label(root, image = img, height=2000, width=2000)
     panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
     root.after(10*500, root.destroy)
     root.mainloop()

 count = 0
 while(count < 3):
    count = count+1
    time.sleep(1)
    if count == 2:
        alert()  
    print count
```

I am using Windows 10. I also have tried to some Wav Sound with this code and some blink LED using arduino by serial. Everything works fine either on CMD and Windows Task Scheduler, except for the Image it's never pop up on The Task Sch.. I have tried to save in pyw, Bat, but still not working. Please Help me guys. :(

Comment: The UI probably pops up on the desktop. If you're not showing the desktop you wouldn't see it. P.S. you need to double up on the ` \ ` characters in your path or use the `r` string modifier: `'c:\\xxxx\\...'` or `r'c:\xxxx\...'`

Comment: What do you mean by "compile using CMD"? Do you mean you ran the script from CMD? It's not like CMD has anything to do with it. It just runs python[w].exe and possibly waits for it to exit.

Comment: With the Task Scheduler, you'll only see a window if you "run only when user is logged on". Otherwise the task runs in session 0, the services session, which doesn't allow applications to access the desktop.